# Can a Yefat Toar be taken from nations who are ineligible for marriage?

Tags: halacha-theory, marriage, women, egypt

My understanding is that a Yefat Toar (Devarim 21:10-14) is forcibly converted and can be married.
The Torah prohibits marrying people from certain nations such as Egypt and Edom for a number of generations (Devarim 23:8-9). Does the Yefat Toar dispensation supersede this consideration? Meaning could a man marry a woman from these nations who is taken as a Yefat Toar even before the multi-generational requirement is met?

Comment: presumably it's the same as a kohein https://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=14982

Comment: @DoubleAA presumably not. A kohen is not allowed to marry a convert irrespective of whence the convert came, this is a question of maintaining lineage/status (kiddushin 4:1) such consideration doesn't necessarily apply to a Yisroel

Comment: I don't understand your response at all.